# Encryption - Can using the same IV for all encryption operations be reasonable in certain scenarios?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes

I understand that when encrypting data, the initialization vector (IV) is usually randomized and stored alongside the encrypted data. Doing so prevents leakage of the underlying data when it is encrypted (e.g., two duplicate inputs produce different cipher texts when encrypted).

If one were to use the same IV for all encryption operations, what would the real security cost of that be? The benefit of using the same IV seems like it would allow the encrypted data to be searchable.

Can it be reasonable to use a static IV, if one can reasonably assume based on the underlying data, that minimal information will be leaked from the encrypted data?

Comment: Why would you want to reuse the IV? I recommend not doing it, ever. And it is probably very hard to quantify the "real security cost" of doing so, using your words.

Comment: @Sajjon Re-using it would allow some more performant search-ability of the encrypted data (at the cost of some information leakage from what I can understand)

Comment: @mattnedrich It depends on the mode of operation and the possible messages. I'd try and see the Q/As on [cryptography that include the initialization-vector tag](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/initialization-vector). If you have a more specific question for a more specific mode, you can ask a question there. In the end, this is not a programming specific question.

Comment: Sometimes the description of a stream cipher will, incorrectly, call the Nonce an IV.  Repeating a Nonce is a serious error for a stream cipher.  Make sure you are using a block cipher, and not in CTR mode, which is effectively a stream cipher made from a block cipher.